# Alamofire request "status_code" = 401 in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, laravel-5, swift3, httprequest

I'm facing this error the whole day. It didn't appear with my old project. I do api post request

```
 let urlstr = "http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login/"

    let url = URL(string: urlstr)

    var param = ["email": "leo@le.com", "password":"111111"]


    request( url!, method: .post, parameters: param)
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response.request)  // original URL request
            print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
            print(response.data)     // server data
            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

            if let json = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(json)")

                //Now you got your value

                print("username\(json)")

            }

    }
```

my info.plist has

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

but recently I've been getting this error

```
SUCCESS
 JSON: {
message = Unauthorized;
"status_code" = 401;
 }
  username{
message = Unauthorized;
"status_code" = 401;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that you are authorize to make the call? It does not seem to be an Alamofire error.

Comment: @RashwanL I agree I don't think it is because when I make the same call from a different project I get ** apicalls[16090:8712574] App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
Optional(http://localhost:8000/api/auth/signup/)
nil
Optional(0 bytes)
FAILURE
** but postman returns login token with no error.

Comment: You need to check your server side what kind of service need to call.Maybe this issue will be from your server side. @leo0019

Answer (score 2):

Status code (401) indicates that the request requires authentication. User/agent is unknown by the server or FORBIDDEN